# Prepopulate ModelMultipleChoiceField Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a website that allows users to follow stocks and see articles based on those stocks. Upon registration the user follows `Stock`s for the first time. After this I would like them to be able to view a page that shows all `Stock`s and which ones they follow. How can I prepopulate a ModelMultipleChoiceField?

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

views.py:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StockFollowForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.user.profile.followed_stocks = list(form.cleaned_data.get('stocks_selected'))
            request.user.profile.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = StockFollowForm() #how do I prepopulate this if there are already followed Stock objects
        return render(request, 'core/test.html',{'form': form})
```

template:

```
<div class = "container">
        <h2 class = "text-center">Register</h2>

        <form method = 'post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div class = "text-center">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type = 'submit'>Follow/Unfollow Stocks</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Stock
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField


class ProfileRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name' ,'last_name')

class StockFollowForm(forms.Form):
    stocks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required =False,
                                           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           queryset=Stock.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the initial value for the `stocks` field:

```
form = StockFollowForm(
    initial={'stocks': request.user.profile.followed_stocks.all()}
)
```

For more on this, check out the [Django docs on providing initial values to a `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)